# SpriteKit: SKPhysicsJointLimit nodes shake and rotate uncontrollably

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have 10 `SKSpriteNode`'s that are connected by physics joints via `SKPhysicsJointLimit.joint(withBodyA:bodyB:anchorA:anchorB:)`. Together, they form a chain that should behave more or less like a real-life chain.

The basic structure of the chain is fine, however **each node kind of shakes and dances about, randomly rotating wildly infinitely**. I have no idea what's causing this problem.

My code:

```
        let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let chains = mainData.getLevelChains()
        var previousChainLink: SKSpriteNode!
        let numOfChainLinks: Int = 10
        
        for i in 0..<chains.count {
            let chainWidth = chains[i].width
            let chainLinkWidth: CGFloat = chainWidth*0.1
            let chainLinkHeight: CGFloat = chainLinkWidth * 0.5
            let halfChainLinkWidth: Double = Double(chainLinkWidth) * 0.5
            
            for j in 0..<numOfChainLinks {
                if j == 0 {
                    //Create the left anchor chainLink
                    let leftAnchor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "chainLink.png")
                    leftAnchor.size = CGSize(width: chainLinkWidth, height: chainLinkHeight)
                    
                    leftAnchor.position = CGPoint(x: chains[i].leftAnchorPosition.x, y: chains[i].leftAnchorPosition.y)
                    leftAnchor.name = "leftAnchor"
                    
                    leftAnchor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: leftAnchor.texture!, size: CGSize(width: chainLinkWidth, height: chainLinkHeight))
                    leftAnchor.physicsBody?.pinned = true
                    
                    addChild(leftAnchor)
                    
                    previousChainLink = leftAnchor
                    
                } else if j == numOfChainLinks-1 {
                    //Create the right anchor chainLink
                    let rightAnchor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "chainLink.png")
                    rightAnchor.size = CGSize(width: chainLinkWidth, height: chainLinkHeight)
                    
                    rightAnchor.position = CGPoint(x: chains[i].rightAnchorPosition.x, y: chains[i].rightAnchorPosition.y)
                    rightAnchor.name = "rightAnchor"
                    
                    rightAnchor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: rightAnchor.texture!, size: CGSize(width: chainLinkWidth, height: chainLinkHeight))
                    rightAnchor.physicsBody?.pinned = true
                    
                    addChild(rightAnchor)
                    
                    let joint = SKPhysicsJointLimit.joint(
                        withBodyA: previousChainLink.physicsBody!,
                        bodyB: rightAnchor.physicsBody!,
                        anchorA: CGPoint(x: Double(previousChainLink.position.x)+halfChainLinkWidth, y: Double(previousChainLink.position.y)),
                        anchorB: CGPoint(x: Double(rightAnchor.position.x)-halfChainLinkWidth, y: Double(rightAnchor.position.y))
                    )
                    
                    joint.maxLength = 1
                    
                    scene?.physicsWorld.add(joint)
                } else {
                    //Create the non-anchor chainLinks
                    let bodyA = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "chainLink.png")
                    
                    bodyA.size = CGSize(width: chainLinkWidth, height: chainLinkHeight)
                    
                    bodyA.position = CGPoint(x: chainWidth * (0.1 * CGFloat(j)), y: screen.height*0.8)
                    
                    bodyA.name = "body\(i)"
                    
                    bodyA.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bodyA.texture!, size: CGSize(width: chainLinkWidth, height: chainLinkHeight))
                    
                    addChild(bodyA)
                    
                    let joint = SKPhysicsJointLimit.joint(
                        withBodyA: previousChainLink.physicsBody!,
                        bodyB: bodyA.physicsBody!,
                        anchorA: CGPoint(x: Double(previousChainLink.position.x)+halfChainLinkWidth, y: Double(previousChainLink.position.y)),
                        anchorB: CGPoint(x: Double(bodyA.position.x)-halfChainLinkWidth, y: Double(bodyA.position.y))
                    )
                    
                    joint.maxLength = 1
                    
                    scene?.physicsWorld.add(joint)
                    
                    previousChainLink = bodyA
                }
            }
        }
```

**Why are these nodes rotating and shaking wildly, and how do I solve the problem?**

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

While I still have no idea *why* I was seeing the behavior I mentioned, I've found a way around it: I'm using `SKPhysicsJointPin` instead of `SKPhysicsJointLimit`. For whatever reason, `SKPhysicsJointPin` doesn't have the wild rotation problem.